# Como unir un .h y un .cc

Tags: c++, poo, clase, object

Acabo de crear dos archivos. El primero es `rectangulo.h`:

```
#ifndef _RECTANGULO_
#define _RECTANGULO_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangulo{
    private:
        int x;
        int y;

    public:
        Rectangulo(int a, int b);
        int area();
};
#endif
```

Y el segundo es su correspondiente `rectangulo.cc`

```
#include "rectangulo.h"
Rectangulo::Rectangulo(int a, int b){
    x = a;
    y = b;
}

int Rectangulo::area(){
    return x * y;
}
```

Ahora lo quiero probar pero no se como hacerlo. ¿Como y donde hago la función main?

Supongo que es lo más fácil pero me han explicado como dividir el código pero no como probar que funciona después.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `main` únicamente necesita la cabecera para funcionar. Ya que lo único que necesita saber es cuánto ocupa la clase `Rectangulo` en memoria y cómo se organizan sus variables y qué funciones tiene.

El resto de la *magia* se produce durante el proceso de enlazado. Es en esta fase cuando el compilador cogerá el código objeto del main y el de la clase `Rectangulo` y con ellas generará el binario final.

Como ves, solo hace falta hacer un include de la cabecera:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "rectangulo.h"

int main()
{
  Rectangulo r(2, 3);
  std::cout << r.area();
}
```